# Select only if record have none associations, or if the associations does not contain certain user id

Tags: sql

I am working on an application, where a user can upload a image, and other people can vote on it.
I don't want to show questions to users, which has already been voted on by the same user, this could be solved by something like

```
SELECT * FROM questions q JOIN votes v ON v.question_id = q.id WHERE v.userd_id != 1
```

But this fail to work, when multiple users have voted. My other issue is that there might not always be votes on the questions, which means that if there is no votes, the question is simply not shown, i tried with a left join, but could't get it to work.

Sadly my sql is a bit rusty, hopefully someone can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude records using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    questions AS q
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    votes AS v 
            WHERE   v.question_id = q.id 
            AND     v.userd_id = 1
        );
```

If you happen to be using MySQL, then you may find that [using `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` performs better](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/):

```
SELECT  q.*
FROM    questions AS q
        LEFT JOIN Votes AS v
            ON v.question_id = q.id 
            AND v.User_ID = 1
WHERE   v.Question_ID IS NULL
```